# Unable to write URL to HREF Properly via hashchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform a document.write() to display a dynamic new.php HREF for each of the 3 conditions below (#pane1, #pane2, #pane3).

Currently I can get the URL to display but only with the single quotes included (which doesn't write the correct value, it just displays/writes the text as one would expect). If I take out the quotes around the newURL variable I get "ReferenceError: newURL is not defined" and the entire Add New text does not display as desired.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){

        var newURL="";

        // Bind the event.
        $(window).hashchange( function(){

          if(location.hash=="#pane1") {
            alert( location.hash );
            newURL="new1.php";
          }

          if(location.hash=="#pane2") {
            alert( location.hash );
            newURL="new2.php";
          }

          if(location.hash=="#pane3") {
            alert( location.hash );
            newURL="new3.php";
          }

        })

        // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
        $(window).hashchange();

      });

    </script>

    <li>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('Add New'.link('newURL'));
      </script>
    </li>
```

Comment: i think single quotes are not required in last line, as newURL is variable

Comment: also try closing the hashchange event handler correctly by adding a ; after })

Comment: `var newURL` is wrapped in a function, hence scoped in that function. The `document.write()` is in the global scope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `document write` could be executed before the document ready event triggers, also that variable is in the document ready **function scope**. try putting the var declaration outside of the jquery scope:

```
var newURL="";

$(function(){
...
```

and then at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('Add New'.link(newURL));
      </script>
```

or also wrap this in a document ready function to make sure this line gets executed after you triggered the hashchange event on the window object.

Comment: Thanks so much Alex, moving the variable declaration did clear up the error. With regard to displaying the "Add New" link I can't get that to work yet. I tried .on('hashchange', function() { and document ready and both have the same result which is it displays the Add New text but that is the only thing that loads on the page and the page hangs/never loads. Thanks again.